# Sinatra db table not created after migration

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, psql, sinatra-activerecord

I am trying to create active record using Sinatra and Sinatra/active record, my migrations are getting migrated to the Postgres database but tables are not getting created in the database, I went through all the possible solutions on stack overflow but its of no use. I tried even deleting my migration files from db/migrate folder but still the same output. What must be the error

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem "sinatra"
gem "pg"    #for postgres
gem "activerecord" 
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
```

**config.ru**

```
require "./app"
run Sinatra::Application
```

**rakefile.rb**

```
require "./app"
require "sinatra/activerecord/rake"
```

**app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/activerecord' 
db = URI.parse('postgres://project1:project1@localhost/*****')
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  :adapter  => db.scheme == 'postgres' ? 'postgresql' : db.scheme,
  :host     => db.host,
  :username => db.user,
  :password => db.password,
  :database => db.path[1..-1],
  :encoding => 'utf8'
 )


class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class CreateNotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :notes do |t|
        t.string    :title
        t.text  :body
        t.timestamps
    end 
  end
  def down
    drop_table  :notes
  end
end
```

**output of migration**

```
user@user-Inspiron-5520:~/rails-apps/project1$ rake db:migrate
== 20150704053019 CreateNotes: migrating      ======================================
== 20150704053019 CreateNotes: migrated (0.0000s)   =============================
```

**db output (psql)**

```
\dt

           List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |   Owner   
--------+-------------------+-------+-----------
 public | schema_migrations | table | project1
(1 row)

project1=# select * from schema_migrations;
   version     
----------------
20150704053019
```

(1 row)

**note:** Project1 user is a super user with all privileges

**EDIT**

**Migrations file 20150704053019_create_notes.rb**

```
class CreateNotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess you've tried doing `rake db:rollback` already, and then re-run?

Comment: Can you post the migration file?

Comment: The migration you are using to create notes table is actually kept in `app.rb`. But the migrate task looks for migrations inside `db/migrate`. If the migration file you gave at the bottom is inside the right directory, then move the migration definition from app.rb to there.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working and I understood my mistake. First of all I did not make any proper work flow and folder structure for my app because of which it came out to be all messy.

Comment: @limekin I would recommend that you put that as an answer because Ankita.P clearly found it helpful and would accept it so you can get rep.

Comment: @IsaiahZwick-Schachter : Ah, I didn't get the notification of Ankita.P's response comment since I wasn't mentioned in it. But I thought the credit of the answer should go to you since you asked for the migration file and I believed you would give the same answer too if you see it :). I just gave the answer asap, so OP can get over the problem quickly.

Comment: @limekin ok I posted an answer. Feel free to edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first like to note that @limekin was the first to get the answer, commenting:

> The migration you are using to create notes table is actually kept in app.rb. But the migrate task looks for migrations inside db/migrate. If the migration file you gave at the bottom is inside the right directory, then move the migration definition from app.rb to there.

I will just go into a bit more detail. The function that you are using to create the table belongs in the migration file, because a migration is what creates, changes and deletes tables, columns, and records.

So to solve your issue just move the function up in your app file into the change function in your migration file.